# browse folder and get user input to create a new file

Tags: c#, user-input

I want to create a file in a directory selected by the user and named it by the user input.
I tried **FolderBrowserDialog** but it didn't prompt me to give a file name:

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
string path = fbd.SelectedPath;
//string FileName; then concatenate it with the path to create a new file
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Should you be using SaveFileDialog instead?

Comment: but he can choose a file instead of create just a name

Comment: SaveFileDialog allows you to select or create a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a *new* file in a folder, so you should:

1. ask the user to select a folder (with FolderBrowserDialog)
2. offer the user a way to type a file name, with an input field (separate from the folder dialog)

Then you concat those 2 infos to get your full file name.

Or you can use SaveFileDialog and check if the file already exists when the user has selected a file (with a File.Exists...). There is a property for displaying an alert when the file does not exists, but not on the other side.
So when you got the DialogResult, use File.Exists and you can alert the user.

Sample for this solution:

In this sample (I hope without errors, cannot test right now):
- I open the saveFileDialog on a button called SaveButton with the SaveButton_Click click method
- I have a SaveFileDialog component on my form, called saveFileDialog1. On this component, the event FileOK is associated to my saveFileDialog1_FileOk method

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set your default directory
    saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

    // Set the title of your dialog
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save file";

    // Do not display an alert when the user uses a non existing file
    saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = false;

    // Default extension, in this sample txt.
    saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // DO WHAT YOU WANT WHEN THE FILE AS BEEN CHOSEN
    }
}

// This method handles the FileOK event. It checks if the file already exists
private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
    {
        // The file already exists, the user must select an other file
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a new file, not an existing one");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: please could you give an example for the second method?

Comment: Done. Let me know if you have problem trying this solution

Comment: Thanks for help, it is very usefull for me, I want just that the default extension will be csv and nothing else (because on ComboBox's Type of the saveFileDialog1 show nothing)

Comment: you can set the default extension with the 'DefaultExt' property of the SaveFileDialog component